# xml to html menu items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

Would like to ask for a pointer or advice. I need to render an existing xml file to html menu items. The string values I will also have to edit but just need some advice as to how to go about in displaying the xml items as html menu items?

Comment: Look at XSLT. It's designed to convert data from XML to any other formt, including HTML.

Comment: Considering it's just for a 'menu', I'd be surprised if XSLT is ultimately the right choice, what server side programming language are you using Arianule?

Comment: @MackieeE - How have you come to that conclusion?

Comment: I use C# predominantly but in this case feel I need to use javascript/jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) to do this. Javascript is able to do this - [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp) is some example code